# Scala script creating DF and temp tables in spark shell - issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, apache-spark, hadoop

```
I have loaded multiple parquet files to create multiple DFs, but when I am using for loop, I am getting errors. 

Markdown and HTML are turned off in code blocks:
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val url_1 = "s3://file_path/folder1.parquet/*"
val url_2 = "s3://file_path/folder2.parquet/*"
val url_3 = "s3://file_path/folder3.parquet/*"
for (url <- Array(url_1 ,url_2 ,url_3)) var parqfile=sqlContext.read.load(url)
for (item <- Array("tb1","tb2","tb3")) parqfile.registerTempTable(item)
```

but I cannot do this because it says I have 
    :1: error: illegal start of simple expression

please help...
Thanks!

Comment: 9 tables? Or 3 tables?

Comment: @thebluephantom 3 tables

Comment: OK, but never looked at it this way, but can't quite follow. tb1 comes from url1?

Comment: Think I got it ah ha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper way to do this, SPARK 2.x not 1.6 but same principles apply. Far simpler, used DF as source. Note the {}.

```
val tb1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
    ("A", "X", "done"),
    ("A", "Y", "done"),
    ("C", "Y", "done"),
    ("B", "Y", "done")
  )).toDF("Company", "Type", "Status")
val tb2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
    ("A", "X", "done"),
    ("B", "Y", "done")
  )).toDF("Company", "Type", "Status")
val tb3 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
    ("A", "X", "done")
  )).toDF("Company", "Type", "Status")

for (tb <- Array(tb1 , tb2 , tb3)) {
     tb.createOrReplaceTempView(s"tb")
}

tb2.show // etc.
```

Comment: var count = 0
for (url <- Array(tb1,tb2,tb3)) 
    {
      val data_set = sqlContext.read.load(url)
      data_set.createOrReplaceTempView("test_tmp" + count)
      count = count + 1      }

Comment: thank you @thebluephantom I made a change to the for loop and it worked.